# Way to call a phone number along with passing a image

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I need to know is there a way to call a phone number along with passing a image to display.... also if i could get the call duration, or set some notification for particular time....

One way is to call using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://123456789"]];
```

but then my application would go in backgound , how to i call my application after phone call end...

Comment: Are you sure you'd like that phone number to appear here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is almost not possible.

Im saying allmost because it might be posibbole to

1. add a temporary contact to the
   address book with the phone number you want.
2. set its image to the image you want.
3. paste the call with the method you wrote.

but still there are 2 problems.

1. you will have somehow to delete the contact afterwords.
2. you can not do the things you asked from the background. and you can not do nothing when a call is active.

Comment: you can not do the things you asked from the background. and you can not do anything when a call is active.

Comment: see , if i get timestamp wen call begins that is b4 i call the code above , i will have startin time only thing is how do i get timestamp wen call ends or how do i make call to my app, so the diff would give me call duration ...

Comment: That is defiantly possible as i have an app that do that.

Comment: so how do i get to call my application after phone call ends?

Comment: hey i found out by using telprompt instead of tel returns after call ends to my app